# How to determine datastore based off of Disk Path?

Tags: powershell, powercli

any vmware powershell people out there? Im hoping someone can help me. Is there an easy way to show me the drive labels of attached disk on a server, and what datastore that disk is on? For example we have an SQL Server with mount point called 'SQL01\Tlog' now how can I find the datastore that the disk is on?
This command shows me the path of each Disk:
(get-vm Computername).Guest.Disks
This command shows me the datastores on the server:
get-vm Computername | Get-Datastore
How can I do it so that I see the path along with the datastore its on?

Answer (score 0):

in the past i had to match a VM's virtual disks against the OS' disks in a reliable way. it is not safe to assume the first disk in a VM's configuration is the first disk in the OS. the method below attempts to match the disks based on serial number first. if that fails, it also tries to match on SCSI target ID. given a computer whose host name and VM name is $CN...

```
#define the computer & VM name
$CN = 'mycomputer'

#get OS disk information
$GWOsplat = `
  @{computername = $CN
  class = 'win32_diskdrive'
  erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
$OSdisk = get-WMIobject @GWOsplat

#get VM disk information
$GVsplat = `
  @{viewtype = ([VMware.VIM.virtualmachine])
  filter = @{name="^$CN`$"}
  property = @('name','config.hardware.device')
  erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
$VM = get-view @GVsplat
$VMdisk = $VM.config.hardware.device | where-object {$_.deviceinfo.label -like 'hard disk*'}

#get the number of SCSI controllers
$controllercount = ($VMdisk.controllerkey | group-object | measure-object).count

#iterate through VM disks
foreach($VMD in $VMdisk)
{
  #get VM disk serial number and SCSI target ID
  $VMDSN = $VMD.backing.UUID -replace '-',''
  $VMDSID = $VMD.unitnumber

  #iterate through operating system disks
  foreach($OSD in $OSdisk)
  {
    #get OS disk serial number and SCSI target ID
    $OSDSN = $OSD.serialnumber
    $OSDSID = $OSD.SCSItargetID
    if(($VMDSN -eq $OSDSN) -or (($controllercount -eq 1) -and ($VMDSID -eq $OSDSID)))
    {
      #matching OSdisk found

      #get datastore
      $DS = get-datastore -ID $VMD.backing.datastore

      #get partitions within OSdisk
      $GWOsplat = `
        @{computername = $CN
        query = "associators of {win32_diskdrive.deviceID='$($OSD.deviceID)'} WHERE resultrole=dependent"
        erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
      $partition = get-WMIobject @GWOsplat

      #get logicaldisks within partitions
      foreach($P in $partition)
      {
        $GWOsplat = `
          @{computername = $CN
          query = "associators of {win32_diskpartition.deviceID='$($P.deviceID)'} WHERE resultrole=dependent"
          erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
        $logicaldisk = get-WMIobject @GWOsplat

        #output custom object mapping drive letter to datastore
        foreach($LD in $logicaldisk)
        {
          [PScustomobject] `
            @{computername = $CN
            datastore = $DS
            drive = $LD.deviceID}
        }
      }
      break
    }
  }
}
```

the reason i only attempt SCSI target ID matching if there is a single SCSI controller is i could not find a reliable way to match a SCSI controller in the OS with a VM's SCSI controller. it should be a very minor drawback since most disks will match on serial number, and most VMs do not have multiple SCSI controllers.

---

## edit 1

below are 2 functions, "group-volumedisk" and "group-VMOSdisk". i did not fully comment them, but they do have some comments, and they are fairly straightforward.

group-VMOSdisk uses group-volumedisk to get a mapping of a computer's win32_volume instances to its win32_diskdrive instances. group-VMOSdisk does mostly what was in the first section of this post.

```
function group-volumedisk
{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param
  (
    [parameter(valuefrompipeline=$true,valuefrompipelinebypropertyname=$true)]
    [alias('CN')]
    [system.string[]]$computername
  )
  begin
  {
    new-variable -option constant -name localhost -value ([system.environment]::machinename)
    new-variable -option constant -name dbgpfx -value "$localhost`: $($myinvocation.mycommand):"
    new-variable -option constant -name dispprop -value @('computername','volume','diskdrive')
    new-variable -option constant -name SB -value `
    {
      begin
      {
        add-type -typedefinition @"
          namespace GDFVNS
          {
            using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct DiskExtent
            {
              public int DiskNumber;
              public System.Int64 StartingOffset;
              public System.Int64 ExtentLength;
            };

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct DiskExtents
            {
              public int numberOfExtents;
              public DiskExtent first;
            };

            public class GDFVname
            {
              public const uint IoctlVolumeGetVolumeDiskExtents = 0x560000;


              [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
              public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
              string lpFileName,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] System.IO.FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] System.IO.FileShare dwShareMode,
              System.IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] System.IO.FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] System.IO.FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
              System.IntPtr hTemplateFile);

              [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
              public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
              SafeFileHandle hDevice,
              uint IoControlCode,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] [In] object InBuffer,
              uint nInBufferSize,
              ref DiskExtents OutBuffer,
              int nOutBufferSize,
              ref uint pBytesReturned,
              System.IntPtr Overlapped);
            }
          }
"@
      }
      end
      {
        $volume = get-WMIobject -class win32_volume -filter "drivetype = 3"
        foreach($V in $volume)
        {
          # get the volume's path and format it properly
          $path = $V.deviceID
          $path = $path.trimstart('\?')
          $path = $path.trimend('\')
          if($path -notlike '\.\*')
          {
            $path = "\\.\$path"
          }
          "$dbgpfx path ($path)" | write-verbose

          #get a handle to the volume
          $handle = [GDFVNS.GDFVname]::createfile($path,[system.IO.fileaccess]::read,[system.IO.fileshare]::read -bor [system.IO.fileshare]::write,[system.intptr]::zero,[system.IO.filemode]::open,0,[system.intptr]::zero)
          "handle ($($handle | out-string))" | write-verbose
          if($handle.isinvalid)
          {
            $lastAPIerr = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::getlastwin32error()
            "createfile call failed ($lastAPIerr)" | write-error
            continue
          }

          #get disk extents of the volume pointed to by $handle
          $returnbytes = new-object -typename system.Uint32
          $DE = new-object -typename GDFVNS.diskextents
          $result = [GDFVNS.GDFVname]::DeviceIoControl($handle,[GDFVNS.GDFVname]::IoctlVolumeGetVolumeDiskExtents,[system.intptr]::zero,0,[ref]$DE,[system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::sizeof($DE),[ref]$returnbytes,[system.intptr]::zero)
          "result ($result)" |  write-verbose
          if($result -eq 0)
          {
            $lastAPIerr = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::getlastwin32error()
            "DeviceIoControl call failed ($lastAPIerr)" | write-error
            continue
          }

          #parse the deviceID of the disk and get its win32_diskdrive
          $deviceID = "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE$($DE.first.DiskNumber)" -replace '\\','\\'
          $diskdrive = get-WMIobject -class win32_diskdrive -filter "deviceID = '$deviceID'"

          #output custom object mapping the win32_volume to its parent win32_diskdrive
          new-object -typename system.management.automation.PSobject -property `
            @{computername = $V.PScomputername
            volume = $V
            diskdrive = $diskdrive}
        }
      }
    }
  }
  process
  {
    foreach($CN in $computername)
    {
      $ICsplat = `
        @{computername = $CN
        scriptblock = $SB
        erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
      try
      {
        invoke-command @ICsplat | select-object -property $dispprop
      }
      catch
      {
        "invoke-command failed`n$_" | write-error
        continue
      }
    }
  }
}
function group-VMOSdisk
{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param
  (
    [parameter(valuefrompipeline=$true)]
    [alias('CN')]
    [system.string[]]$computername
  )
  begin
  {
    new-variable -option constant -name localhost -value ([system.environment]::machinename)
    new-variable -option constant -name dbgpfx -value "$localhost`: $($myinvocation.mycommand):"
  }
  process
  {
    foreach($CN in $computername)
    {
      #get OS disks
      $GWOsplat = `
        @{computername = $CN
        class = 'win32_diskdrive'
        erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
      $OSdisk = get-WMIobject @GWOsplat

      #get mapping of volumes to disks
      $voldiskmap = $CN | group-volumedisk

      #get VM disks
      $GVsplat = `
        @{viewtype = ([VMware.VIM.virtualmachine])
        filter = @{name="^$CN$"}
        erroraction = [system.management.automation.actionpreference]::stop}
      $VM = get-view @GVsplat
      $VMdisk = $VM.config.hardware.device | where-object {$_.deviceinfo.label -like 'hard disk*'}

      #get SCSI controller count
      $controllercount = ($VMdisk.controllerkey | group-object | measure-object).count

      #iterate through VMdisks
      foreach($VMD in $VMdisk)
      {
        #get the VMdisk serial number and SCSI target ID
        $VMDSN = $VMD.backing.UUID -replace '-',''
        $VMDSID = $VMD.unitnumber
        foreach($OSD in $OSdisk)
        {
          #get the OSdisk serial number and SCSI target ID
          $OSDSN = $OSD.serialnumber
          $OSDSID = $OSD.SCSItargetID
          if(($VMDSN -eq $OSDSN) -or (($controllercount -eq 1) -and ($VMDSID -eq $OSDSID)))
          {
            #matching OSdisk found

            #get datastore
            $DS = get-datastore -ID $VMD.backing.datastore

            #get volumes within this OSdisk
            $volume = ($voldiskmap | where-object {$_.diskdrive.deviceID -eq $OSD.deviceID}).volume

            #output custom object mapping volume to datastore
            foreach($V in $volume)
            {
              [PScustomobject] `
                @{computername = $CN
                datastore = $DS
                volume = $V.name}
            }
            break
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

connect to your vSphere server, then pipe $CN to group-VMOSdisk.

group-volumedisk was adapted from: http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/PowerShell_Get-MountPointData_Cmdlet

Comment: cwr Thanks for the help.  I ran your script against a SQL server I have, it returned both drive Letters, C and E.  However we have multiple Mount points under E that are on their own Disk, how can I modify this script to account for Mount points as well ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: edited original post with functions to support disks mounted in folders